# Cannot import name 'operator'

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to create my first custom operator.

I have a `airflow` folder, a `dags` folder and a `plugins` folder.

Within the `plugins` folder I have the `operators` folder.

My operator is in the `operators` folder.

In my `operators` folder I have the following `__init__.py` file:

```
from operators.my_operator import MyOperator

__all__ = [
    'MyOperator',
]
```

In my plugins folder I have the following `__init__.py` file:

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin

import operators

# Defining the plugin class
class NewOperator(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "test_operator"
    operators = [
        operators.MyOperator
    ]
```

and then from my dag I'm calling my operator like this `from airflow.operators import MyOperator`

From the UI I see the error `cannot import name 'MyOperator'`

What's wrong?

Comment: As per the documentation : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/plugins.html   Can you try -  from airflow.operators.test_operator import MyOperator